# Comparing Linear Models with Multiple Interactions

Tags: r, linear-regression

For an assignment, needing to determine the linear model with interaction terms for a data set and I can do this manually by creating different linear models and then performing an ANOVA test.

What I am wondering is if there any function within R that will check all possible combinations of linear model interactions for a given main effects model? (a function similar to the same way that it handles stepwise variable selection)

I've had a look but my knowledge of R isn't strong and I may have already browsed past the function.

Comment: To examine every model, have a look at `regsubsets` from the `leaps` package which does an exhaustive search. Also `stepAIC` can do a hillclimbing search of models including interaction terms (include these in the upper scope)

Comment: ahhhh didn't realise the stepAIC also covered interaction terms

Answer (score 0):

First column is a dependent variable(y)(mainClass) and we make all possible linear regression models.
There are three independent variables(X,Y and Z).
 mainClass ~ X , mainClass ~ X+Y , mainClass ~ Y+Z  and all other combinations are explored. 
--code description
Creating a data frame where first column is mainClass and other columns are variable
Finding column names excluding first column(mainClass)
Having the combination of column numbers
Having the combination of formulas to be used in linear regression

### Building linear regression

```
        DF<- data.frame(mainClass=1:10,X=rnorm(10,3,1),Y=seq(4,40,4),Z=seq(100,10,-10))              
Cols <- names(DF)      
Cols <- Cols[! Cols %in% "mainClass"]      
comb_id <- unlist(lapply(1:n, function(i)combn(1:n,i,simplify=F)),recursive=F)
```

Formulas <- sapply(comb_id,function(i) paste("mainClass~",paste(Cols[i],collapse="+")))
lapply(Formulas,function(i) lm(as.formula(i),data=DF))